# About the first decimal of $\sqrt {n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Do we have :

$$\sup\{\sqrt {n!} - E(\sqrt {n!});   n\in I\!\!N\}=1?$$

Where $E(\cdot)$ is the integer part function, and $n!=1\times 2...\times n$.

Comment: By $\sqrt{n}!$ do you mean $\Gamma(1+\sqrt{n})$?

Comment: Or maybe $\sqrt{n!}$?

Comment: I mean $\sqrt{n!}$

Comment: Question seems clear now, after the edits.

Comment: I would expect $\sqrt{n!}$ to be equidistributed modulo $1$.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence But of course I have no proof.

Comment: In general we don't have any good techniques for controlling the distribution of an exponentially growing sequence modulo 1.  For instance nobody knows how to prove that the sup of $\{ 10^n \pi \}$ is $1$, though everyone believes it is true.  I don't see any reason why $\sqrt{n!}$ would be any easier than $10^n \pi$ (or $10^n \sqrt{2}$, for that matter).